# weblogic springframework TypeMismatchException failed to convert

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, bea

After Successful deployment of web project, I am getting the following error when I tried to access the web application from browser.

```
2011-12-17 17:37:52.887  AdminServer <consumerFaultTracking> [-] ERROR Context initialization failed : org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn-(228) 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.bt.custc.faulttracking.dao.FaultTrackingProfileAccountDAOImpl#e71be2' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/action-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyAccessExceptionsException: PropertyAccessExceptionsException (1 errors); nested propertyAccessExceptions are: [org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [com.bt.custc.userdetails.service.UserdetailsServiceImpl] to required type [com.bt.custc.profileaccountservice.service.ProfileAccountService] for property 'profileAccountService']
PropertyAccessExceptionsException (1 errors)
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [com.bt.custc.userdetails.service.UserdetailsServiceImpl] to required type [com.bt.custc.profileaccountservice.service.ProfileAccountService] for property 'profileAccountService'
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.doTypeConversionIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:733)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:890)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValues(BeanWrapperImpl.java:917)
```

action-servlet.xml content :

```
<property name="accountService">
    <bean class="com.bt.custc.faulttracking.service.FaultTrackingProfileAccountServiceImpl">
        <property name="profileAccountDAO">
            <bean class="com.bt.custc.faulttracking.dao.FaultTrackingProfileAccountDAOImpl">
                <property name="profileAccountService">
                    <ref bean="profileAccountServiceImplRefBean" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Please let me know the resolution if anyone has faced the same issue earlier. I do not think I am allowed to make the code changes as this is supposedly working for other team members.

Is there anything which I might be missing from weblogic configuration point of view or may be duplicate jars etc... Please enlighten me if there would be any such possibilities which could lead to this error?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing related to WebLogic in this exception. In your `/WEB-INF/action-servlet.xml` file, you're trying to set the property `profileAccountService` of a bean of type `com.bt.custc.faulttracking.dao.FaultTrackingProfileAccountDAOImpl` to an instance of `com.bt.custc.userdetails.service.UserdetailsServiceImpl`. The property is of type `com.bt.custc.profileaccountservice.service.ProfileAccountService`, and `UserdetailsServiceImpl` is not an implementation of `ProfileAccountService`.

Comment: Thanks JB for your response and confirmation that this issue is not related to weblogic.

Comment: I am not sure how it is being pointed to UserDetailServiceImpl (action-sevlet snippet is attached for your reference).  In my entire action-servlet.xml, I could not find 'UserDetailsServiceImpl' anywhere else.

Comment: What's the difinition of the bean profileAccountServiceImplRefBean?